# How to handle non-2XX response codes in RoboSpice?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, robospice

In my API server returns HTTP 400 response code if request does not pass validation, and provides detailed message, that should be parsed as the response.

For example:

```
public class RegistrationResponse {
    private String emailError; // Detailed message. Null if no error occured
}
```

But Robospice (Retrofit + OkHttp) fires onRequestFailure() with message "retrofit.RetrofitError: 400 BAD REQUEST" in this case and, of course, does not parse anything.

How should I make it parse the response in case if response code is not 2XX?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare Retrofit methods that return HTTP `Response` objects and check the raw object in your `loadDataFromNetwork()` for the status you need. This way, however, you will skip the out-of-the-box functionality of parsing responses and will have to do that manually.

Therefore, you should also find a way to reuse the `Converter` passed to your `RestAdapter` in the `RetrofitSpiceService`. Overriding the [`RetrofitSpiceService#createConverter()`](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/blob/release/extensions/robospice-retrofit-parent/robospice-retrofit/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/retrofit/RetrofitSpiceService.java#L38) method is probably the simplest way to achieve this.